# iOS background app to read Bluetooth advertisement

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy

Is it possible to build an iOS App that can run in the background, with minimal battery consumption, and collect BLE advertisements payloads of specific devices? Does iOS prevent such apps to work in the background even when the user has given consent?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible to build such an app that can continuously scan in the background. Check Apple's Documentation on the subject:-

- [CoreBluetooth background processing for iOS apps](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/CoreBluetoothBackgroundProcessingForIOSApps/PerformingTasksWhileYourAppIsInTheBackground.html)

Also check the following links with more details on the subject:-

- [BLE device keep connect with iPhone when app terminates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39353262/ble-device-keep-connect-with-iphone-when-application-terminate)
- [Leveraging background Bluetooth for a great user experience](https://punchthrough.com/leveraging-background-bluetooth-for-a-great-user-experience/)
- [iOS background Bluetooth: BLE scanning when phone is locked](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/652592)

However, there are limitations to the speed of the scan and the data retrieved from the scan. See the links below for more info:-

- [Scan peripheral in background](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/109253)
- [iOS: scan and connect to a BLE peripheral in the background](https://medium.com/@cbartel/ios-scan-and-connect-to-a-ble-peripheral-in-the-background-731f960d520d)
- [Overcoming the iOS background Bluetooth limitations](https://github.com/opentrace-community/opentrace-ios/issues/4)

Comment: Thank you,  Youssif Saeed. My specific use case needs to collect BLE advertisements from any peripheral. Collect from multiple tracking devices my company sells to the customers (in line with Tile, Airtag etc). Do you see any specific challenge with the iOS app since the UUID is not known beforehand?