# Can anyone give me an idea of how a bluetooth device like silent beacon can send a command to the phone while the screen is closed

Tags: ios, bluetooth

I am talking the silentbeacon.com personal safety alarm device.  How is it able to connect with the phone with bluetooth while the screen is locked.  I am looking for an IOS solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just because the screen is locked on the iOS device doesn't mean it cannot do any Bluetooth functionality. iOS devices have a special background mode that allows them to continuously read BLE adverts and also communicate with remote BLE devices. You can find more about this here:-

- [CoreBluetooth background processing for iOS apps](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/CoreBluetoothBackgroundProcessingForIOSApps/PerformingTasksWhileYourAppIsInTheBackground.html)
- [BLE device keeps connecting with iPhone when app terminates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39353262/ble-device-keep-connect-with-iphone-when-application-terminate)
- [iOS - BLE scan and connect to peripheral in background](https://medium.com/@cbartel/ios-scan-and-connect-to-a-ble-peripheral-in-the-background-731f960d520d)